# Cannot access Azure Key Vault from on-premises private IP network via VPN. IP private address range is forbidden

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-keyvault

I have Azure virtual network with subnets connected to on-premises network via VPN. Everything is addressed with 10.0.0.0 private address space. The communication is working with other Private Endpoints. I have created Key Vault with Private Endpoint and firewall. Firewall is configured as follows:

- Allow access from: Private endpoint and selected networks
- Virtual networks: only Azure subnets can be listed ( I need acces from on-premises )
- Firewall: IPv4 CIDR allow only public IPs. 10.0.0.0 address space is forbidden.

How to access key vault from on-premises network?
The Azure Portal doesn't allow me to add Keys, Secrets nor Certs. The message is: Firewall is turned on and your client IP address is not authorized to access this key vault.

When trying to add my on-premises address range I go a message: Invalid value found at properties.networkAcls.ipRules[0].value: 10.99.0.0/16 belongs to forbidden range 10.0.0.0–10.255.255.255 (private IP addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to access the key vault from an on-premise network **with a private endpoint**, you need to neither whitelist the on-premise private IP address (IP network rules are only allowed for public IP addresses) nor any virtual network in the firewall of the key vault. You can [confirm that the key vault firewall is properly configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-diagnostics#3-confirm-that-the-key-vault-firewall-is-properly-configured)

> The following statements also apply to firewall settings:
>
> - The private links feature doesn't require any "virtual network" to be specified in the key vault firewall settings. All requests using
>   the private IP address of the key vault (see next section) must work,
>   even if no virtual network is specified in the key vault firewall
>   settings.
> - The private links feature doesn't require specifying any IP address in the key vault firewall settings. Again, all requests using the
>   private IP address of the key vault must work, even if no IP address
>   was specified in the firewall settings.

You just need to ensure that your clients are using a private endpoint to access the Azure key vault also you can [validate the DNS resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-diagnostics#5-validate-the-dns-resolution). The key vault hostname (example: fabrikam.vault.azure.net) should be resolved into an IP address (example: 10.1.2.3).

If you read or list the keys from the Azure portal on your local machine. This actually does not use a private endpoint, you just access or manage the key vault via the Azure portal. In this case, you need to [look up the public IP](https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup) of the local client then add it to the firewall of the Azure key vault.

Comment: I have a relevant question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72080875/1232087) in case you have a time for a suggestion/comment