# Unable to access key and secrets in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-virtual-network, azure-security

I am the owner of an Azure Key Vault that I created. I created a `key` and a `secret` a day before. But today when I tried to create another key and secret, the `Generate/Import` button on top in the right pane is disabled and below it a following message is displayed:

> Firewall is turned on and your client IP address is not authorized to access this key vault.

`Networking` section of the Key Vault has the following settings: `Selected Networks` and `Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this filewall: Yes`.

**Question**: Why I am getting the above warning and how can we fix it. I was able to create a Key and secret a day before.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the Firewall or add the client IP to the list of allowed IPs.  At this time your client machine's IP address is not authorized to access the Key Vault and isn't a trusted Microsoft Service.

Answer (score 0):

Only selected networks are allowed. What is funny the web browser client matters not the portal. You need to add your IP address to the list: IP address or CIDR. You can find it by using services like: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip+address

The option: Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall -
works only for trusted services listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-vnet-service-endpoints#trusted-services